# Problem switching culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i have 2 links for switching culture.
if i click  one link, the program call a method with this code:

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(ln);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(ln);
        return RedirectToAction("index");
```

If i look with debug the culture is correctly changed, but in the Index redirection, the cultureUI is not changed.

I'm trying locally with visual studio web server(Cassini).

thank you

Comment: It shouldn't switch threads as you are redirecting. Just in case, check the threads window to make sure you are still on the same thread in the Index method.

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing from links on the view. However we do not put the code in action but rather a method on a base controller class. This is the action:

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string cultureCode)
    {
        string returnUrl = string.Empty;
        if (Request != null)
        {
            returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            //Write to the cookie
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Language", cultureCode));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
    }
```

And this is the method in the base Controller class:

```
 protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        //Retrieve from cookies
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["Language"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
        {
            string culture = cultureCookie.Value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
            }
        }
        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved symply adding this method in the global.asax:

```
   void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageFromSession);
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageFromSession);
}
```

This method is called everytime i call an action in  a controller.

**In this way i don't use cookies and I do not need to inherit any controller from a base controller.**

I think it is the better solution.